# HID over bluetooth LE in javascript

Tags: javascript, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to an Bluetooth LE barcode scanner (https://www.newland-id.com/en/products/nwear/wd4-ring-scanner) in Chrome.
I'm able to connect to the scanner an the read the battery level following this example: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/battery-level.html

But I can't find the right service to use for the barcode itself. I have found one, but when I try to use that I get 'requestDevice() called with a filter containing a blocklisted UUID or manufacturer data.'

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
   filters: [{
       services: ['00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb']
   }]
})
```

Is there a way to bypass this, since I want to connect this specific device? Or can I use a different way? I also tried using WebHID but that isn't supported in Chrome for Android yet which is a requirement.

Comment: The battery level will have a primary service UUID=180F and a characteristic UUID=2A19. The barcode will have a primary service UUID=1812 and a characteristic UUID=2A4D. It can be read directly, but will almost certainly be notify-capable, so if its notifications are enabled, the value will be sent by the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

`00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` is the service UUID for Human Interface Device (HID) and is blocked by the [GATT blocklist](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/registries/blob/master/gatt_blocklist.txt):

> ```
> # org.bluetooth.service.human_interface_device
> # Direct access to HID devices like keyboards would let web pages
> # become keyloggers.
> 00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
> ```

Web Bluetooth operates at the transport level and lacks sufficient granularity to selectively block access to specific HID collections or reports. Applications that need to access Bluetooth LE HID services should instead use [WebHID API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebHID_API). WebHID blocks access to reports containing sensitive mouse or keyboard inputs while allowing other reports, including barcode scanner reports.